# Тестирование UI в Unity3D

Tags: unity3d, test-automation, ui, плагин

Очень интересует, каким образом можно тестировать новый UI  в Unity, чтобы можно было имитировать пользовательский ввод, проверять состояние контролов после изменения в системе и т.п.

Возможно, кто-то уже этим озадачился. Мне поиском решения найти не удалось.

Answer (score 1):

Игры очень сложно тестировать по определению, потому что что-то происходит постоянно. Даже если добавить тестирование GUI, это вам слабо поможет, потому что GUI будет зависеть от состояния в игре, которое в свою очередь зависит от тысяч событий ввода, постоянно изменяется и т.п.

Вы можете использовать юнит-тестирование для проверки поведения пользовательского интерфейса, если достаточно абстрагируетесь, как и в случае с другими частями логики. Но тестирование именно GUI в игре вряд ли возможно в полноценном виде.

Если позволяют архитектура и производительность, пользуйтесь юнит-тестированием. В остальном полагайтесь на ручное тестирование.

Comment: Мы разрабатываем виртуальные тренажеры, поэтому практически все действия и реакции запротоколированы. С помощью  юнит-тестов я могу проверить поведение контроллеров на объекте, как они меняются под действием команд с сервера например. Целостность сцены и поведение объектов на сцене проверяем UnityTestTools. Единственное что остается, это интерфейс через который пользователь управляет настройками сцены. Хотелось именно проверить что изменил настройку видимости объекта и объект действительно получил команду на выключение объекта ну и т.п.