# Авто Тесты Unity

Tags: unity3d, test-automation

подскажите пожалуйста,каким образом можно подружить Unity UI с созданием сценариев?(для firebase test lab и т.д.). Создание сценариев через Android Studio учитывает только нативные кнопки android-a. Заранее Благодарен
[Тестирование UI в Unity3D](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/412722/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-ui-%D0%B2-unity3d) - эту тему видел,но возможно,за 3 года изменилось что-то и я не нашёл этого

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нету поддержки Unity UI фреймворками, поэтому нужно через код делать нажатие и отслеживание событий,и относительно их результата считать пройденным тест или нет